# Incompatible type when using generic

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class TrafficReportMapper implements RowMapper<TrafficReport> {

   @Override
   public TrafficReport mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
     // Do something here
     return new TrafficReport(....);
   }
}
```

`TrafficReport` is a POJO and I want to extend it with something like `DayTrafficReport` and to create a new mapper that extends `TrafficReportMapper`. So I changed `TrafficReportMapper` as follows:

```
public class TrafficReportMapper<T extends TrafficReport> implements RowMapper<T> {

   @Override
   public T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
     // Exactly the same code as before
     return new TrafficReport(....);
   }
}
```

Only this time I get

> Incompatible Types: Required T; found TrafficReport

But the thing is that `TrafficReport` must be of type `T`. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: You can't return a `TrafficReport` object of the method expects you to return `T`. `T` may be `TrafficReport`, but it may also be `SomeTrafficReportSubclass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create `TrafficReportMapper<DayTrafficReport>` your method will become:

```
@Override
public DayTrafficReport mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
    return new TrafficReport(....);
}
```

(not really since generics get erased, but it's a good way to think about it.)

But `TrafficReport` **is not** a subtype of `DayTrafficReport`, so you can't return it like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your `class` as follows:

```
public class TrafficReportMapper<T extends TrafficReport> implements RowMapper<TrafficReport>
```

... assuming:

```
interface RowMapper<T>  {
    public T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum);
    ...
}
```

Then if you have:

```
class TrafficReport{}
```

...and...

```
class DayTrafficReport extends TrafficReport{}
```

You can initialize as such:

```
TrafficReportMapper<DayTrafficReport> trm = new TrafficReportMapper<DayTrafficReport>();
```

Comment: First of all I had a mistake, the return type after the change is `T`. I'm Sorry.

Second - I want to have the `TrafficReportMapper` with the same functionality as it have had until now but to be able to extend it to other types as well. Bottom line - I need to have a `TrafficReportMapper` that returns `TrafficReport` but I want it to be more generic

Comment: I think this: `DayTrafficReport report = trm.mapRow(null, 0)` will throw `ClassCastException` and that is not the behaviour you would want from a generic class.

Comment: @kajacx you're totally right. Will remove that from my answer as it defiles generics entirely. Thanks for noticing